# A responsive-vertical-horizontal-absolute box with Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can I create a responsive-vertical-horizontal-absolute box with Bootstrap?

It would be good if the solution is without,

```
bottom: 0; right: 0; // they cause some bugs in jquery ui's draggable
```

css,

```
.centerBox {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  border:2px solid red;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

html & bootstrap,

```
<div class="col col-xs-2 centerBox">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you want your box to be centered into the viewport.
You can do this with some jquery.

```
function centerBox(){
  var winH = $(window).height();
  var winW = $(window).width();
  var boxH = $('.cenetrBox').height();
  var boxW = $('.cenetrBox').width();
  $('.cenetrBox').css({
    left: Math.ceil((winW-boxW)/2) + 'px',
    top: Math.ceil((winH-boxH)/2) + 'px'
  });
}
```

to be this function responsive include and:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
  centerBox();
});
```

Hope this will help you.

And if you want a border do not forget to include in css:

```
.centerBox {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  border:2px solid red;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

}